# ERROR: recursive reference to query "najdi_tot" must not appear within its non-recursive term

Tags: postgresql, cte

I have a trouble with the following CTE query:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE najdi_tot(sj) AS (
    SELECT nad FROM s_vztah WHERE pod=581
    UNION
    SELECT pod FROM s_vztah WHERE nad=581
    UNION
    SELECT sv.nad FROM najdi_tot n, s_vztah sv 
    WHERE sv.pod = n.sj
    UNION
    SELECT sv.pod FROM najdi_tot n, s_vztah sv 
    WHERE sv.nad = n.sj
  )
  SELECT array_agg(sj) FROM najdi_tot
```

Following error occurs:

```
ERROR:  recursive reference to query "najdi_tot" must not appear within its non-recursive term
LINE 6:     SELECT sv.nad FROM najdi_tot n, s_vztah sv 
                               ^
```

I made a google search ( `postgresql "recursive reference to query" "must not appear within its non-recursive term"` ) and found nothing but maillists where I failed to find the solution (perhaps it is there, but hidden in discussion).

What should my query do is to find all rows linked from a table connecting two rows in the same table (`nad` and `pod`).

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem just by trying, but I have posted it here because it seems not to be well documented anywhere in the internet. I hope those who will make the same mistake later will not be so confused as I was!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185140/self-joins-in-recursive-cte-recursive-reference-must-not-appear-more-than-once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [self-joins in recursive CTE: \`recursive reference must not appear more than once\`?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185140/self-joins-in-recursive-cte-recursive-reference-must-not-appear-more-than-once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by multiplication in the recursive calls. When I deleted one of them, the problem was solved:

```
  WITH RECURSIVE najdi_tot(sj) AS (
    SELECT nad FROM s_vztah WHERE pod=581
    UNION
    SELECT pod FROM s_vztah WHERE nad=581
    UNION
    SELECT sv.nad FROM najdi_tot n, s_vztah sv 
    WHERE sv.pod = n.sj
  )
  SELECT array_agg(sj) FROM najdi_tot
```

Then I realized that the relation is symmetrical - at the first call I get all the linked rows and recursion only adds the row I had in the beginning. So I removed the recursion at all and everything is OK:

```
  WITH najdi_tot(sj) AS (
    SELECT nad FROM s_vztah WHERE pod=581
    UNION
    SELECT pod FROM s_vztah WHERE nad=581
  )
  SELECT array_agg(sj) FROM najdi_tot
```